# Why is this Materialize form only submitting one value?

Tags: materialize

I am trying to get the form located at http://dfauction.org/intakeform-m.html to successfully submit. When it submits, $POST only contains a single value, rather then the entire form.

I've checked my syntax and checked on the backend... a simple form I made not in Materialize worked fine. I'm new to Materialize so it may be something stupid.

The submission PHP file is as follows:

```php
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    }
?>
```

I expect the var_dump to contain the list of fields in the form, but it only contains

```
array(1) { ["action"]=> string(0) "" }
```

which is just the submit button, and not any of the data from the actual form.

edit: Looks like it also will POST the switch, but not any of the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the names on the form elements:

Before:

```
<input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" required>
<label for="first_name" class="">First Name</label>
```

After:

```
<input id="first_name" name="first" type="text" class="validate" required>
<label for="first_name" class="">First Name</label>
```